# Will new monitor fix choppy video?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, webgl

**Context**

I have an eMachines computer I bought from Walmart about 2-3 years ago. It came with Windows 7 and everything was great. I'm an HTML5 developer, and I do a lot of 2D and 3D development, both with HTML5's 2D canvas rendering context and with WebGL. I had never had any performance problems running on Windows 7.

Recently I decided to get rid of Windows, and I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on it. The video card is an nVidia GeoForce 6150SE.

**Here's my frustration and question:**

The default graphics driver (NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates)(version 173-updates) works greats (smooth playback and everything). The problem: It won't run WebGL no matter what I try.

If I install any other driver (version current, version current-updates, etc.), I can get WebGL to play, but any video playback or HTML5's request animation frame is super choppy. I've tried every last suggestion I found online (I've been trying to get this to work for a few weeks now).

The monitor I use is a bit dated. It's a Samsung SyncMaster 740b.

**Question:**

If I buy a new monitor and use it with the latest graphics card driver I have, is the choppiness likely to go away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no. your display has (nearly) nothing to do with the video playback speed.

It's more that the free drivers don't speed up video decoding, while the proprietary does. It'd be good to know which graphics chip you actually have.

Comment: I have a nVidia GeForce Ge6150 SE nForce 430. The driver I have installed is directly from nVidia.